# Is it possible to create a new T-SQL Operator using CLR Code in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlclr

I have a very simple CLR Function for doing Regex Matching

```
public static SqlBoolean RegExMatch(SqlString input, SqlString pattern)
{
    if (input.IsNull || pattern.IsNull)
        return SqlBoolean.False;

    return Regex.IsMatch(input.Value, pattern.Value, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

It allows me to write a SQL Statement Like.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.table1 WHERE dbo.RegexMatch(column1, '[0-9][A-Z]') = 1
-- match entries in col1 like 1A, 2B etc...
```

I'm just thinking it would be nice to reformulate that query so it could be called like

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.table1 WHERE column1 REGEXLIKE '[0-9][A-Z]'
```

Is it possible to create new comparison operators using CLR Code. (I'm guessing from my brief glance around the web that the answer is ***NO***, but no harm asking)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you cannot. You can create functions, stored procedures, triggers and so forth - but there's no provision to create new T-SQL operators or commands. Not in SQL Server 2008R2 either, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

In this link you can see how to declare operators in SQLCLR:
http://msftengprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS2008!User-Defined%20Data%20Type%20(UDT)%20Sample&referringTitle=Home

For example:

```
    public static SqlBoolean operator ==(ComplexNumber c1, ComplexNumber c2)
    {
        return c1.Equals(c2);
    }
```